# php dynamic meta description empty

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, meta-tags

While executing this code from a webservice, the title and keywords are shown in the meta tags as expected. The description stays empty though. How do I put dynamic array content from $array in the description? Ps eg $array[3] won't work either.

```
$array = $result->AAAResult->AAA->A;

$teller = count($array);

$titeltekst = "{$teller} quantity: $r";


$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$options = $doc->getHeadData();

$options['title'] = $titeltekst;
$options['metaTags']['standard']['keywords'] = "keywords - test";
$options['metaTags']['standard']['description'] = $array;

$doc->setHeadData($options);
```

Comment: What does `$array` look like? Can you show us a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` of it? I'm mostly curious what the indexes are and how many dimensions.

Comment: just added an example page: http://test.huisx.nl/energie/1731249/rozenburglaan-72/rotterdam

with this piece of code:
foreach($array as $k=>$v)

{


$end = strtotime($v->Einddatum);



  print "
    <tr>
    <td>
       <ul>
     <li><b>Naam      : {$v->Naam}</b></li>
     <li><b>Status    : {$v->Status}</b></li>
     <li><b>Aanbieder : {$v->VerstrekkerNaam}</b></li>
     <li><b>Bedrag    : {$v->Bedrag}</b></li>
     <li><b>Begindatum   : " . date("d-m-Y",strtotime($v->Begindatum)) ."</b></li>
        <li><b>Einddatum    : " . ($end ? date("d-m-Y", $end) : 'Niet gegeven') . "</b></li>

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to assign an array directly to anything that expects a string, but you can use `implode` assuming that all the values are also strings.

```
$string = implode(', ', $array);
```

Comment: I can't imagine a **description** that needs to be comma separated?

Comment: my server doesn't like this code for dinner: returns a blanco page.
The values are also dates so probabbly not all strings etc.

Comment: In that case, you may want to build the string yourself. Do so by looking at the content and decided how you want to combine it.

Comment: @datasage How can I build the string myself with eg the Name variable? Could you please give me a hint?

It is being shown in the page by using this piece of code:

foreach($array as $k=>$v)

{


print "

Naam      : {$v->Naam}

Comment: So what you have is an array of objects, do you have more than one object in the array?

Comment: Yes, I think there are about 12 objects (name, startdate, organisation etc etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just added eg.

```
$string .= $v->Naam;
```

and;

```
$options['metaTags']['standard']['description'] = $string;
```

, if you choose to create the string on the Naam (Name) object of the Array.